# Can't control Threads from different Methods WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm writing a small Keylogger for some statistics about my typing.
The Keylogger works fine, but now i want to implement it to a wpf to have a better control.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Thread ThreadLog = new Thread(Log);
    Thread ThreadRefreshForm = new Thread(refreshForm);
    Thread ThreadAutoSave = new Thread(AutoSave);
    ThreadLog.Start();
    ThreadRefreshForm.Start();
    ThreadAutoSave.Start();
}

private void btn_ThreadLogStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ThreadLog.IsAlive == true)
    {
        ThreadLog.Abort();
    }
```

This gives me an Error @ `ThreadLog.IsAlive`. How can i solve the Problem?
Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: You declared ThreadLog in constructor and then access it from method btn_ThreadLogStop_Click. Does ThreadLog declared somewhere else?

Comment: No, But if i declare it over the constructor like: public Thread ThreadLog = new Thread(log); the program shows me an error like "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'MainWindow.log()'"  i use some propertys of my labels and checkboxes in the log method. What to do now?

Comment: Big drum-roll, and the error you getting is??

Comment: How about declaring `ThreadLog` in the scope of your class and initializing in the constructor?

Comment: You should **never ever ever** call `Thread.Abort()`. I heard it described this way - "if you want to stop a car, just shoot the driver - the car will stop, but you just won't know what damage the car will do in the process". Calling `.Abort()` on a thread will cause all sorts of damage to your app domain. The **only** legitimate time to call it is when you are forcing your application to shut down.

Comment: so i should use some vars to check in each thread to stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking the correct way how to end threads is like this

```
private volatile bool m_Stop;           

public void ThreadLoop()
{
  while(!m_Stop) {
    // do some work
  }
}

// starting
new Thread(ThreadLoop).Start();

// "force" end
m_Stop = true;
```

Or if you prefer tasks over threads (which I do):

```
public void ThreadLoop(CancellationToken token)
{
  while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    // do some work
  }
}

var cancelation = new CancellationTokenSource();
// starting
new Task(() => ThreadLoop(cancelation.Token), cancelation.Token).Start();
// "force" end
cancelation.Cancel();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should declare your `ThreadLog` somewhere else and initialize it in the constructor, such that the method can access the `ThreadLog`:

```
private Thread ThreadLog;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ThreadLog = new Thread(Log);
    ...
}

private void btn_ThreadLogStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ThreadLog.IsAlive == true)
    {
        ThreadLog.Abort();
    }
```